# "la partie droite" ou "la partie de droite" ?

Tags: prépositions, constructions, phrase

Je suis en train d'écrire: "*cette valeur est positive quand la partie droite descend*" et je me demande s'il ne faudrait pas plutôt écrire "*cette valeur est positive quand la partie **de** droite descend*". Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Comment: La partie droite de quoi ?

Comment: la partie droite d'une poutre (horizontale)

Comment: valeur, numéros?

Comment: Poutre rigide montée sur un axe ou poutre déformée ?

Comment: _Cette valeur est nulle quand la poutre est à niveau._

Comment: En fait, le contexte est l'application de forces sur une poutre et une convention de signe sur la valeur de l'effort tranchant au sein de cette poutre. Par définition, dans une poutre horizontale, l'effort tranchant est positif quand la force tout à droite est dirigée vers le bas (--> la partie de droite descend) et négative quand elle est dirigée vers le haut

Comment: RN est *la partie de droite*, elle se situe dans *la partie droite* du spectre politique français. ;)

Answer (score 1):

En attendant plus de précision :

> Cette valeur est positive quand la poutre s'incline vers la droite.

---

Mise à jour:

> *En fait, le contexte est l'application de forces sur une poutre et une convention de signe sur la valeur de l'effort tranchant au sein de cette poutre. Par définition, dans une poutre horizontale, l'effort tranchant est positif quand la force tout à droite est dirigée vers le bas (--> la partie de droite descend) et négative quand elle est dirigée vers le haut*

À la lumière de cette précision, j'éviterais de dire que la partie (de) droite *descend* car :

- elle est immobile une fois la force appliquée (hors rupture)
- la déformation qu'elle a subi par rapport à son état original peut être très faible, voire (en théorie) nulle si la poutre est infiniment rigide.

Je proposerais donc :

> Cette valeur est positive quand la force s'applique (de haut en bas) sur la partie droite de la poutre.

ou

> Cette valeur est positive quand la force s'applique (de haut en bas) sur le côté droit de la poutre.

Il n'est probablement pas indispensable de préciser le sens de la force verticale.

Answer (score 0):

« Partie droite » est plus courant, mais on peut dire « partie de droite ».

[image]

Il ne faut pas se fier strictement au diagramme qui peut inclure des cas de « partie droite » de sens « partie qui n'est pas sinueuse » ou « partie qui n'est pas tordue », mais ils doivent être rares, comme un examen de cette [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22partie%20droite%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) tend à le montrer.

Pour « côté de droite/côté droite » on trouve que de nos jours les deux formes sont utilisées avec la même fréquence.

[image]

Le manque de parallélisme dans l'usage montre qu'il n'y a pas de véritable question d'idiomaticity sur le plan de la fréquence d'usage ; « partie de droite » est aussi idiomatique que « partie droite ».

De nos jours on dit cependant « côté droit », et peu « côté droite ».

Certains noms ne s'utilisent pas avec « partie de droite ».

[image]

« Partie de droite de » semble peu usité ([réf. 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22partie%20de%20droite%20de%20la%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr), [réf. 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22partie%20de%20droite%20du%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)).

- Pour la partie de droite de la route
- composait la partie de droite de la rue dite des Mauvais Chevaux
- de la partie de droite de la fig. 15
- sur la partie de droite de la machine
- elles donneront la partie de droite de la mantisse
- Quant à la partie de droite de la fig. 9
- une grande partie de droite de la Seine
- supposons la partie de droite de la poutre enlevée et remplacée
- Partie de droite de la même scène

♦

- on additionne la partie de droite du domino de la première ligne
- la partie de droite du pont sera alors non chargée
- la partie de droite du barrage de Hermalle - sous - Argenteau
- la partie de droite du transept
- Détail de la partie de droite du portail occidental
- Tant sur cette partie de droite du panneau d'avant que sous la bande refaite plus tard
- indiquées à la partie de droite du bulletin

« Partie de droite » semble appartenir à un usage vieillissant.

Comment: On ne sait même pas de quoi il s'agit. -1

Comment: @Lambie Vous avez raison ; les noms les plus usités  avec « partie droite » ne le  sont pas avec « partie de droite ».

Comment: *On dit peu "côté droite"* : tu m'étonnes ! Ce serait sûrement une bonne idée d'accorder correctement l'adjectif...

Comment: @jlliagre Ce n'est qu'une question de convention ; ce n'est plus l'adjectif, c'est le nom « droite » et la combinaison est alors nom composé.

Comment: Bon, je ne vais pas perdre mon temps comme avec la *quasitotalité*, mais c'est du même tonneau. Je t'invite quand même à tenter *côté de droite* contre *côté droit* dans Google NGrams avant de tirer des conclusions hâtives.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est une forme que l'on trouve dans le passé récent et il est difficile de l'analyser autrement qu'en tant que nom composé : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20droite%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr.

Comment: Amen............

Comment: Merci beaucoup, j'ai ajouté des précisions dans les commentaires de ma question

Comment: Attention, la partie droite n'a pas forcément le même sens que la partie de droite. La partie droite peut aussi faire référence à un aspect rectiligne.